# ViewPager doesnt' work properly with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-tablayout

I have fragment with the next layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_color"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Discover.TextAppearance.Tab"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I start app on cold, I'll see correct TabLayout with all needed tabs and 2 first pages into viewpager (set offset limit 1 for viewpager).

After I swipe ViewPager to 3 page, I'll see nothing. It looks like fragment is missing inside ViewPager, but I see logs and fragment is work fine.

If I send app to background and turn back, all pages will be visible.

If I remove tablayout and drop all cache, this bug won't repeat.

Initialization code:

```
final TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) view.findById(R.id.tabs);
final ViewPager page = (ViewPager) view.findById(R.id.pager);
final DataAdapter adapter = new DataAdapter(someData);
page.setAdapter(adapter);

tabs.setupWithViewPager(page);
```

Comment: use coordinatorLayout as root instead of LinearLayout

Comment: @bryanc, I've tried, result is the same.

Comment: why you set offset Limit 1 if you have 3 pages ? viewpager now will cache just 2 pages

Comment: @bryanc, I have more then 3 pages. Third page and all next pages will be invisible. I use limit 1 for reduce using memory in app. Don't you use this trick?

Comment: i leave defaults think that caches just 3 pages it seems your pager adapter may cause such situation .

Comment: it needs some code to view, e.g. viewpager initializing, fragment onCreate etc

Answer (score 0):

Could you pass more code? And you should consider RelativeLayout, and just skip the FrameLayout.